# Determine if there is a repeated substring of two lowercase letters , and if so, output the repeated substrings and the number of occurrences

Tags: c#, substring

When I type aaabbaabb, only aa and bb are counted, but not bb.

This is code

```
namespace Test5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            string[] words = new string[20];
            int[] times = new int[20];

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!input.All(x => x >= 'a' && x <= 'z'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("lnputting illegal characters");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    bool isSame = false;
                    string sourse = input.Substring(i, 2);
                    int j = i + 2;
                    while (j < input.Length - 2)
                    {
                        string target = input.Substring(j, 2);
                        if (sourse == target)
                        {
                            times[n]++;
                            if (Array.IndexOf(words, target) == -1)
                            {
                                isSame = true;
                                words[n] = target;
                            }
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    if (!isSame) { n++; }
                }
                for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
                {

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(words[k]))
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"{words[k]} {times[k] + 1}");
                    }



                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "only aa and bb are counted, but not bb." – how can bb be counted and not counted at the same time? Is bb counted or not?

Comment: Should a single letter *counted twice*? How many `aa` do we have there - `aaab` - two pairs or just one (i.e. can we reuse the middle `a`)?

Comment: like aa 3 ab 2 bb 2

Comment: That is aa and ab are counted.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for a *pattern*

> repeated substring of two lowercase letters

the very first idea which comes to mind is to match with a help of a
*regular expression*. Assuming that you *don't want to reuse the letter* (I based it on `int j = i + 2` fragment), i.e for `"aaa"`
we return just one pair `(0, 1)`, not two `(0, 1)` and `(1,2)` (middle `a` at index `1` is reused) the pattern is

```
(\p{Ll})\1
```

where

```
(\p{Ll}) - a single Unicode (you haven't said "English") letter;
           change \p{Ll} into [a..z] if you want just English letters
\1       - the very same matched letter
```

Code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "aaabbaabb";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"(\p{Ll})\1")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .GroupBy(match => match.Value, match => match.Index)
  .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
  .Select(group => $"{group.Key} appears {group.Count()} times at {string.Join(", ", group)}");

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
aa appears 2 times at 0, 5
bb appears 2 times at 3, 7
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRH8sP)